# Is there a way to connect MySql Database to eclipse?

Tags: android, mysql, eclipse, connection

Is there a way to use eclipse to establish connection to mysql database.
Also is if that can be connected, will that be connection made in such a way that even the app would be connected to the mysql database

Yes, the question is kind of dumb but rather than being in doubt all the time, i would rather look a bit foolish and ask stupid questions!

Comment: No, why would eclipse connect to a database?  Its a compiler, not an application.  Now it would be possible to connect an ANdroid app to a db over the net, but the usual way to do it is to put a web service in between and have it serve the data to the mobile app-  having random clients connect directly to the database is a security risk.

Comment: It's actually an IDE.  Compiling is one of the things that it does.  There are any number of reasons why you might want to connect your database to your IDE.

Comment: Please check this link http://itsolutionsforall.com/eclipse_sql.php . Hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Database tools to connect a MySql database to Eclipse. See a tutorial [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseDataToolsPlatform/article.html).

You can't connect an Android application to a MySql db directly. You would need to provide a web service that will connect with the db and allow the Android application to do read/write operations on it.

Comment: If the user meant sqlite since we're talking about Android you might also note that they can grab a copy of the database with DDMS.  Once local it can be opened and viewed with a number of visualization tools, editors, etc.